# Behaviour of tstrsplit in a function

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset with string data, derived from quasi-JSON data. A sample of the data can be seen here: https://github.com/krishnavemuri/safegraph/blob/master/nyc_reprex.csv

I tried the following code to get the data from one of the variables:

```
    nyc_bhdt <- nyc_sd[,tstrsplit(bucketed_home_dwell_time,",")]
nyc_bhdt[,origin_census_block_group := nyc_sd$origin_census_block_group]
nyc_bhdt_long <- melt(nyc_bhdt, id.vars = "origin_census_block_group")
nyc_bhdt_long[,variable := NULL]
nyc_bhdt_long[,tstrsplit(value,":")]
nyc_bhdt_long[,value := NULL]
nyc_bhdt_long[,bin := sub('.*""(.*)"".*', "\\1", bin)]
nyc_bhdt_long[,bin := str_replace(bin,"-",".")]
nyc_bhdt_long[,count := as.numeric(str_remove(count,"\\}"))]
nyc_bhdt <- dcast(nyc_bhdt_long[!(is.na(bin))],origin_census_block_group ~ bin, fill = 0)
```

This gave me the output in the way I wanted it:

However, when I tried to write the same code as a function, since I also have a few hundred other similar files to process, each with 6 such variables, I run into errors, especially with `tstrsplit`:

```
process_jsonized_data <- function(dt, vname){
  new_dt <- dt[,tstrsplit(vname,",")]
  new_dt[,origin_census_block_group := dt[,.(origin_census_block_group)]]
  new_dt_long <- melt(new_dt, id.vars = "origin_census_block_group")
  new_dt_long[,variable := NULL]
  new_dt_long[,`:=`(bin = tstrsplit(value,":",keep = 1),
                    count = tstrsplit(value,":",keep = 2))]
  new_dt_long[,value := NULL]
  new_dt_long[,bin := sub('.*""(.*)"".*', "\\1", bin)]
  new_dt_long[,bin := str_replace(bin,"-",".")]
  new_dt_long[,count := str_remove(count,"\\}")]
  new_dt <- dcast(new_dt_long[!(is.na(bin))],origin_census_block_group ~ bin, fill = 0)
  new_dt
}
```

The error:

```
Error in tstrsplit(value, ":", keep = 2) : 
  'keep' should contain integer values between 1 and 1.
In addition: Warning message:
In setDT(ans) :
 Error in tstrsplit(value, ":", keep = 2) : 
  'keep' should contain integer values between 1 and 1. 
7.
stop("'keep' should contain integer values between ", min(1L, 
    length(ans)), " and ", length(ans), ".") 
6.
tstrsplit(value, ":", keep = 2) 
5.
eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) 
4.
eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) 
3.
`[.data.table`(new_dt_long, , `:=`(bin = tstrsplit(value, ":", 
    keep = 1), count = tstrsplit(value, ":", keep = 2))) 
2.
new_dt_long[, `:=`(bin = tstrsplit(value, ":", keep = 1), count = tstrsplit(value, 
    ":", keep = 2))] 
1.
process_jsonized_data(dt = nyc_sd, vname = cols_c_nested_data[[1]])
```

I can't work out what is causing the error. I have tried wrapping `strsplit` inside `transpose` within the `data.table` and selecting the second object in the resulting list, but that didn't work. Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Try ` dt[,tstrsplit(get(vname),",")]` if you are inputting a string or convert to symbol and evaluate or another option is specify it in `.SDcols` and then do the split on `.SD[[1]]`

Comment: @akrun: I don't want to run tstrsplit on the vname variable, I want to run it on the value variable obtained after tstrsplit(vname) > melt(dt) > value. If you take a look at the variable named `bucketed_home_dwell_time` in the sample data I posted, hopefully you'll see why I had to do this.

Comment: But, ` dt[,tstrsplit(vname,",")]` line won't run i.e. the reason I used `get` to returnn the value of that column from `vname`

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with multiple ways. One option is `get` - returns the value of the column as the input 'vname' is a string of column name from `cols_c_nested_data[[1]]`

```
dt[,tstrsplit(get(vname),",")]
```

Another option is to convert to `symbol` with `as.name` or `as.symbol` and then `eval`uate

```
dt[,tstrsplit(eval(as.name(vname)),",")]
```

Or another option is specify the column name in `.SDcols`

```
dt[,tstrsplit(.SD[[1]],","), .SDcols = vname]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need to do a little replacing of the `"" content ""` with `"content"` and then any json library will work.

You can remove the duplicate `""` like so:

```
nyc_bhdt<-read.csv('json.csv')
nyc_bhdt_json <- data.frame(lapply(nyc_bhdt, function(x) {gsub('""', '"', x)}))
```

Then you can use:

```
require(RJSONIO)
fromJSON(as.character(nyc_bhdt_json$bucketed_distance_traveled[1]))

#which returns the following

16001-50000           0      >50000   2001-8000      1-1000   1001-2000  8001-16000 
          6          11           3           5           5           1           1
```

The important thing to notice, wrapped the cell in `as.character()` when parsing your new cells, because r saw these as categorical content.

You can suppress this when reading the `csv` too, or use the above, which ever works best for you.

Then just iterate over the cells and decide how to compile those outputs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpful! I tried this approach first, using `fromJSON` from the `jsonlite` package, but ran into a different error: process_jsonized_data(dt = nyc_sd,vname = cols_c_nested_data[[1]])
nyc_sd[,bucketed_home_dwell_time := str_replace_all(bucketed_home_dwell_time, pattern = "\"\"", replacement = "\"")]
 Gave me 
Error: parse error: trailing garbage
          -360":5,"<60":15,">1080":24} {"721-1080":10,"361-720":2,"61-
                     (right here) ------^
Which is why I abandoned this path. But this is promising. I'll report back.